# ¿Cómo cambiar la etiqueta de una propiedad desde una acción (por código en tiempo de ejecución) en OpenXava?

Tags: java, openxava

Las etiquetas en OpenXava se especifican en los archivos i18n. Pero, ¿qué pasa si necesitamos cambiar la etiqueta en tiempo de ejecución dependiendo de cierta lógica (desde una acción, por ejemplo).

Digamos que tenemos una entidad con una propiedad ganancias, pero si el valor de la propiedad es negativo queremos cambiar la etiqueta "Ganancias" por "Pérdidas". Como en este código de acción:

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
    // ...
    BigDecimal ganancias = (BigDecimal) getView().getValue("ganancias");
    if (ganancias.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
        // Aquí quiero cambiar la etiqueta de ganancias de "Ganancias" a "Pérdidas"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La clase View tiene un método setLabelId() para cambiar la etiqueta de una propiedad. Aunque recibe un id de etiqueta del archivo de etiqueta i18n, si envías una etiqueta que no es una clave en el archivo i18n, la etiqueta se mostrará literalmente. También puedes enviar la etiqueta entre ', en cuyo caso siempre se muestra literalmente. Es decir, puedes usar esto en tu acción:

```
getView().setLabelId("miPropiedad", "Ésta es mi propiedad");
```

Y entonces la etiqueta para miPropiedad será "Ésta es mi propiedad". Aunque es mejor usar un id del archivo i18n en lugar de directamente la etiqueta, es decir puedes escribir el código de arriba así:

```
getView().setLabelId("miPropiedad", "estaEsMiPropiedad");
```

Y en el archivo de etiqueta i18n añade:

```
estaEsMiPropiedad=Ésta es mi propiedad
```

Así, puedes escribir tu código de esta manera:

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
    // ...
    BigDecimal ganancias = (BigDecimal) getView().getValue("ganancias");
    if (ganancias.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0) {
        getView().setLabelId("ganancias", "perdidas");
    }
}
```